# How do I reload the datatables when I click the button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I have button "add data", When "add data" is clicked, the datatables will increase in data. but it hasn't been loaded automatically (still reloading manually). how so if the "add data" button is clicked on the automatic reload datatables?

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/krs/daftarPengajuan',
        columns: [
            { data: 'kode_mk', name: 'kode_mk' },
            { data: 'nama_mk', name: 'nama_mk' },
            { data: 'jml_sks', name: 'jml_sks' },
            { data: 'semester', name: 'semester' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action' }


        ]
    });

});
</script>
```

Controller

```html
$result = \DB::table('matakuliah')

           ->leftJoin('kurikulum','matakuliah.kode_mk','=','kurikulum.kode_mk')
           ->where('matakuliah.kode_mk',$row->kode_mk)
           ->where('kode_jurusan',$jurusan)
           ->get();
 
 return Datatables::of($result)
  ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
   $action = '<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm add-data" onClick="tambah_pengajuan(\''.$row->kode_mk.'\',\''.$row->semester.'\')"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Ambil</button>';

  return $action;
  })

->make(true);
```

Thanks for time

Answer (score 4):

I think you are interested with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#users-table').DataTable({... // your datatable configuration 
    $('.add-data').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [
            'data',
            'goes',
            'in',
            'each',
            '<td>'
        ] ).draw( false );
     } );

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('.add-data').click();
} );
```

For more [go here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).

If you are interested in reloading data from the API, you can do something like this:

```
t.ajax.reload();
```

To learn more on this [go here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   var user_tbl = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/krs/daftarPengajuan',
        columns: [
            { data: 'kode_mk', name: 'kode_mk' },
            { data: 'nama_mk', name: 'nama_mk' },
            { data: 'jml_sks', name: 'jml_sks' },
            { data: 'semester', name: 'semester' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action' }


        ]
    });
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
        user_tbl.ajax.reload(null,false);
    });
});
</script>
```